# Why does water damage the lungs but amniotic fluid doesn't?

Tags: human-biology, development, respiration, breathing, lungs

I've read that near-drowning causes lung damage due to water inhalation. How come this is not the case with amniotic fluid? Taking this further, would lukewarm purified oxygenated water cause damage (if hypothetically there was no CO2 buildup in the blood)? Is it the pressure differential and/or movement caused by there being a mix of both liquid and gas inside the lungs at the same time that causes the damage to the lung and alveoli (the motion tearing or crushing alveoli perhaps)? Is it an issue of consistency or temperature? Meaning, if all the air in the respiratory system was instantly changed to oxygenated purified water, would it still cause damage if the water was not the right thickness or temperature? Given the right fluid concoction, is it theoretically possible for full molecular exchange to occur indefinitely in a liquid inside the lungs (both oxygen and CO2)? Can I hypothetically become Aquariumman or a Hairy Porter munching on quality Gillyweed?

I'm very sorry for the long list of queries, but I've searched extensively for the answers to these questions, and yet still haven't found a more detailed answer than what amounts to 'it is normal and healthy for fetuses to circulate amniotic fluid through their lungs, getting water in your lungs is neither of those things, please go see a doctor'. And so that's what I'm hoping to do here. I'd greatly appreciate a more detailed answer from someone who specializes in the respiratory system (being a fan of fishy Superheroes or dodgy Wizards is appreciated but not required). A heartfelt thank you to all who answer my questions, and may everyone who is reading this have many a wonderful weeks ahead! :)

Comment: The level of saltiness is critical. Look up Isotonic, compare with hypotonic

Comment: You already know that amniotic fluid isn't water. So how is it different? It's an interesting fluid. Tell us what you've learned about how it's different from water. There is no Neonatologist or Pulmonologist here, and if there was, they would not answer so basic a question without evidence (not just guesses or your claim) of trying to find a solution to your question This site requires some research to be shown (hover over the down vote button; it's also a close vote reason.)

Comment: Part 1: For proof that my claims of having researched aren't bogus, I shall answer off the top of my head (I've only just noticed the comments). I know that fetal lung fluid is very similar to, and formed from, amniotic fluid (though they're not completely the same), since it has more chlorine (released by the lungs I believe) which is why I indicated purified water in my question. Amniotic fluid itself also has many things in it (enzymes and proteins and such) that facilitates cell growth, which is why I asked whether a special concoction could facilitate molecular exchange. Part 2 cont.

Comment: Part 2: I know that some sort of mechanism regulates and maintains the pressure in the fluid in the lungs by releasing the excess, hence my question of whether pressure was an issue. I also know that the sacs that the alveoli are in are very delicate, hence my question of whether the movement could cause damage. As indicated by Wrangler, I know that the amniotic fluid is salty to facilitate chemical reactions, but not so salty as to disrupt cell function. The saltiness also plays a big part in getting the fetal lung fluid out of the lungs just before delivery I believe. Part 3 cont.

Comment: Part 3: I have a Fin Econ background and have 0 formalised education in Bio or Chem after grade 10, since I chose physics for my grade 11-12 IBDP. This means all I know about biology after that comes from self research into curious topics in my free time from studying in Uni. This unfortunately severely restricts my ability to understand Bio papers/articles in as much detail as I'd like in a reasonably timely manner. I'm also curious about absolutely everything, not just biology, hence I find myself with a little knowledge about lots of things, rather than in-depth for some, except finance. :)

Comment: As you stated, fetal lung fluid is not the same as amniotic fluid, and the direction of fluid flow is from the fetal lung into amniotic fluid/fetal GI tract, not amniotic fluid into fetal lungs. Fetal lung fluid is secreted bu the fetus' developing lungs to keep them expanded. Does this change your question(s) at all?  IOW, amniotic fluid doesn't normally reach fetal alveoli. As to O2 exchange with the right solution, yes, it can occur, but there needs to be a mechanism to circulate the fluid such that O2 is continuously introduced and CO2 removed.

Comment: Part 1: Thank you immensely Anongoodnurse for your answer and for such quick replies! However, I was completely certain that fetuses did indeed inhale and exhale amniotic fluid, and that it was only changed (not secreted) into fetal lung fluid by the lungs releasing certain chemicals (such as chlorine) into the amniotic fluid that was being inhaled from around the baby. And I was also absolutely certain that the alveoli/air-sacs were indeed exposed to the fluid as well. Part 2 cont.

Comment: Part 2: In fact, I found myself to be so darned certain of these two views that I decided to go back and research them again to see if my memory was failing me and I'd somehow started getting early-onset dementia at 23! (:D) Here're the results of my (admittedly quick and of shallow depth) reconducted research: The Children's Minnesota web page at ChildrensMN.org states that "The unborn baby “breathes” the fluid into the lungs, where it pushes open the air sacs and stimulates them to grow". Part 3 cont.

Comment: Part 3: Furthermore, WhatToExpect.com states that "Muscle contractions bring amniotic fluid in and out of the lungs" and that "It may even support the development of alveoli, tiny air sacs on the lungs". This view is supported by many different types of reputable sources as well. For instance, Medical News Today states in a news article that "Developing babies are surrounded by amniotic fluid, and their lungs are filled with this fluid... babies begin taking “practice” breaths. But these breaths... only refill the lungs with more amniotic fluid". Part 4 cont.

Comment: Part 4: And also, BabyCenter.com is a parents' help website that states "26 weeks: Baby begins inhaling and exhaling amniotic fluid". These views are even supported by Bio education websites. For example, OpenTextBC.ca is a Canadian education website for British Columbia, and it states that "Fetal breathing movements involve muscle contractions that cause the inhalation of amniotic fluid and exhalation of the same fluid". And another Edu-site called LumenLearning.com has a course that states that "the fetus “practices” breathing by inhaling amniotic fluid in utero".

Comment: **N.B. Not everything you read on the internet is true.**

Comment: @ShaptarshiJoarder you should [edit] your question to add all necessary details instead of stating them in comments. Make your question readable, understandable, and self contained so that any user who has a similar question does not need to scroll through comments.

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler - Now that few people are looking at this question, it doesn't matter if non-fatal drowning occurs in salt or fresh water, so isotonicity isn't really the issue. People tolerate small amounts of inhaled fluids well enough, but larger amounts can wash away surfactant, and causes shunting.

Comment: Thanks for new info @anongoodnurse; in response I read the wikipedia article on pulmonary shunt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Fetal lungs are filled with lung fluid produced by lung epithelial cells, not amniotic fluid. Amniotic fluid aspiration *in utero* can be catastrophic. So your question is based on an inaccuracy.

---

> Why does water damage the lungs but amniotic fluid doesn't?

My question back to you is, how do you know that amniotic fluid isn't harmful to fetal lungs?

There is a common misconception that fetal lungs are filled with amniotic fluid. In fact, it's so common that even many physicians mistakenly believe this.

From [a book chapter titled *Amniotic Fluid: Physiology and Assessment* published in 2008](https://www.glowm.com/section-view/heading/Amniotic%20Fluid:%20Physiology%20and%20Assessment/item/208#.YgGlAmBOnzU), this misconception is discussed briefly:

> Because amniotic fluid is more hypotonic than fetal plasma, it is postulated that exposure of amniotic fluid to the fetal alveolar capillary bed results in net movement of water from the amniotic cavity into the fetus. Although radioisotopes have been discovered in fetal lungs after intra-amniotic instillation, this quantity has been small and inconsistent,2 leading investigators to question the actual contribution of fetal respiration to amniotic fluid removal. **In fact, surface-active phospholipids originating from the fetal alveoli are found in the amniotic cavity, leading to suggestions that the fetal lungs may actually be a net contributor to amniotic fluid volume.**

This, in 2008, despite the fact that fetal lung fluid was shown to be produced by fetal lungs in 1948. (That paper, unfortunately, is unavailable.) By 2018, that misconception was corrected in medical textbooks, e.g. Avery's Diseases of the Newborn, Tenth Edition (2018) in which can be found the following:

> Fetal lung fluid is a product of the epithelial lining of the developing lung (Wilson et al., 2007; Helve et al., 2009), averaging 4–6 mL/kg per hour. The resistance imparted by laryngeal abduction results in fluid accumulation to a total volume of 20–30 mL/kg during gestation, which generates an end-expiratory pressure of approximately 2–4 cmH2O. **The composition of fetal lung fluid is distinct from that of both amniotic fluid and plasma**, as illustrated in Table 42.2.

More succinctly:

> During fetal life the lung develops as a liquid-filled organ. [This liquid is produced by the fetal lung and leaves via the trachea from where it is either swallowed or enters the amniotic sac.](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1440-1681.1995.tb01988.x) Fetal lung liquid plays a crucial role in the growth and development of the lungs by maintaining them in a distended state.

Fetal lungs produce fluid that keeps the lungs expanded and developing normally. Though there is evidence of diaphragmatic activity as early as 12 weeks gestation, amniotic fluid does not enter the lung with these diaphragmatic movements because the fetal larynx closes during "inhalation" preventing the entrance of amniotic fluid. When it relaxes, a small amount of lung fluid escapes the trachea, some of which is swallowed, and the rest contributes to amniotic fluid.

> Fetal breathing movements contribute to the [efflux of lung fluid into the AF](https://www.nature.com/articles/7211290), but about half of the effluent is swallowed rather than entering the AF.

[Amniotic fluid aspiration in utero can cause death](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fped.2019.00116/full) because amniotic fluid is loaded with keratinized epithelial cells from the baby's skin and other things that can injure the lungs.

Before the baby's first breath, all the fetal lung fluid is quickly absorbed by the lungs into the interstitial space, allowing for air to enter the lungs.

Edited to add: You wanted a specialist to answer this question.  Well, here is a [letter to the editor of *Pediatric Pulmonology*](https://d197for5662m48.cloudfront.net/documents/publicationstatus/54476/preprint_pdf/c0055a35154ba836979b38e6fc4997f6.pdf), a journal about the lungs you referred to in your question, from a Neonatologist,  entitled *Fetal lung fluid: Not the same as amniotic fluid*. In it, the Neonatologist corrects a mistake by another Neonatologist in one of the articles in this *specialty journal*! So it shouldn't be a surprise that so many others get it wrong, too.

An exerpt:

> However, I wanted to bring attention to a statement in the introduction where the author states that the “preterm infants’ lungs are filled with amniotic fluid”. This is not accurate and appears to be a common misconception, particularly among medical students and junior residents despite recognition of fetal lung fluid as being a separate entity from the amniotic fluid as originally described in 1948 by Jost and Policard.

Comment: Thank you so much for this amazingly in-depth and easy-to-understand answer! Finally one of my endless number of curiosities have been quenched. Hope you and your family have a most fantastic week ahead! :)

Comment: @ShaptarshiJoarder - Feel free to hit me with another. I learned a fair bit here, too. :)

Comment: As soon as I have another biology curiosity that my research can't seem to answer, I'll be sure to do so! It seems fishy wizards shall remain in fiction for now.